# Add role in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

How can I add a Role in the new ASP.NET Identity system (1.0)?
There is a `UserStore` class but no `RoleStore` class.

I can't find any documentation on this issue.

Comment: There is a Simple Role providers which lets you restrict access to parts of your application by Roles. You can easily create Roles such as “Admin” and add Users to Roles.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
RoleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(
                  new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new MyDbContext()));
var roleresult = RoleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(roleName));
```

Comment: We could also put this in our Startup.Auth.cs file as follows. ``RoleManagerFactory = () => new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>());`` and then copy the usage of the UserManagerFactory.

Comment: instead of    MyDbContext() use  ApplicationDbContext()   or search for your IdentityDbContext inheritedclass

Answer (score 41):

Starting with the .NET Framework 4.5, Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) has been fully integrated into the .NET Framework.

I would advice to examine the possibility, in my opinion the preferred, to implement Authorization through Claims ([Expressing Roles as Claims](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545448.aspx)).

When the IsInRole() method is called, there is a check made to see if the current user has that role. 
In claims-aware applications, the role is expressed by a role claim type that should be available in the token.

The role claim type is expressed using the following URI: 
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"

So from the **UserManager** you can do something like this (without the RoleManager):

```
var um = new UserManager();
um.AddClaimAsync(1, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "administrator"));
```

Claims can simplify and increase the performance of authentication and authorization processes. 
You can use the roles stored as claims to eliminate back-end queries every time authorization takes place.

Using Claims you will not need the RoleStore anymore (at least for the equivalent authorization purposes...)

Comment: Is there a new URI for the role claim types? Because the provided URI is not available..

Answer (score 7):

I used below snippets in one sample asp.net web page **page_load** for starting to grasp the way ASP Identity works

```
   UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
    var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext());
    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);
    var applicationRoleAdministrator = new IdentityRole("superadmin");
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists(applicationRoleAdministrator.Name))
    {
        roleManager.Create(applicationRoleAdministrator);
    }
     ApplicationUser applicationUserAdministrator = userManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);

    if (!userManager.GetRoles(applicationUserAdministrator.Id).Contains("superadmin"))
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/account/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=" + Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
    }
```

Of course below ApplicationDbContext is automatically generated with ASP.NET 4.5+ templates like below

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
    }
```

Also Create application Role Manager class too

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        //return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    }
}
```

also add below line in your startup.Auth.cs => ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) method

```
  app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

And then in your controller:

```
private ApplicationRoleManager _roleManager;

public ApplicationRoleManager RoleManager
{
    get
    {
        return _roleManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationRoleManager>();
    }
    private set
    {
        _roleManager = value;
    }
}
```

I am new to this Identity Stuff and I am not sure if it is necessary or I am doing it clean and right, but these steps worked for me

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET identity is claims aware with respect to roles. That really confused me because in the previous system you configured membership and role providers in web.config.

The issue for me is that I have code like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("some role")
```

Fortunately, this logic still works. You can see the logic in the `CreateAsync` function in ClaimsIdentityFactory.cs which is in `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core`.  One of the arguments is `UserManager`. It asks it if it `SupportsUserRole` and if so then it calls `GetRolesAsync` and adds each role as a claim to the `ClaimIdentity`. There is no need to do this yourself.

`IsInRole` uses claims as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545448.aspx

Comment: ASP.NET Identity (at least v2.0 from what I can tell) does indeed have a `RoleManager`; it's located in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` namespace and you'll find it being used in several of the sample/starter applications I believe.