# ASP.Net MVC Security AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, security

I'm making a MVC4 with EF6 web application where Administrators are allowed access to certain pages. In this case the Administrators are allowed to access the Departments page.

I differentiated my administrators from normal users by using  `public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }`  in my User.cs class.

Whenever I sign into a user account where isAdministrator = true and I try click on my Department's index.cshtml it redirects me to the log in page instead of the Department page. Am I using AuthorizeAttribute correctly?

[image]

DepartmentController.cs

```
   [Authorize(Roles = "isAdministrator")]
    public class DepartmentController : Controller
    {
          ...
    }
```

Users.cs

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public bool IsAdministrator { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you setup the **Role** `isAdministrator` ?

A simple boolean property in a class is not going to do this for you.

Refer to the following articles for more information about how to use / create Roles.

[creating-roles-in-asp-net-identity-mvc-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697226/creating-roles-in-asp-net-identity-mvc-5)

[Extending-and-Modifying-Roles](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/727054/ASP-NET-MVC-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-R)

Comment: Yeah I haven't ! I'll look into the links you've suggested.