# Error when instantiating a RoleManager to add roles to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

Trying to add a role to the database following this: [Creating Roles in Asp.net Identity MVC 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19697226/creating-roles-in-asp-net-identity-mvc-5)

and/or this:
[Add role in ASP.NET Identity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541101/add-role-in-asp-net-identity)

I don't want Claims based authorization, just Roles, so I want to create a role using the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.RoleManager`.

The following code:

```
    public static class InitializeDb
    {
        public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(services.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>>()))
            {
                using (var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context)))
                {
                   ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

produces the following error:

**There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'roleValidators'** of 'RoleManager.RoleManager(IRoleStore, IEnumerable>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, ILogger>, IHttpContextAccessor)'  SmartNetWorker..NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0

Apparently I have to supply the **roleValidators** parameter... or? Am I missing something?

Google says nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resolve `RoleManager`:

```
public static void Initialize(IServiceProvider services)
{
    using (var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```